# Left-aligning content inside a button

Tags: reactjs, css

I've been struggling for hours now trying to align an icon and text inside a button to the left. Currently the button is stretched and looks like this:
[image]

I want the chevron arrow and text to be left aligned inside the button. How to achieve this? (I'm using microsofts ui-fabric, don't think the css here interfere, i don't get any text aligning even if i remove them or change DefaultButton to a regular Button)

Render method:

```
public render(): JSX.Element {
    const { isCollapsed } = this.state;
    const { buttonText, collapsibleSectionText } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <DefaultButton
                onClick={this._toggleCollapse} className="CollapsibleSection"
            >
                {isCollapsed ? <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronUp" aria-hidden="true" /> : <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronDown " aria-hidden="true" />}
                &nbsp; <p>{buttonText}</p>
            </DefaultButton>
            {isCollapsed && collapsibleSectionText}
        </div>
    );
}
```

css:

```
.CollapsibleSection {
margin-top: 2%;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DefaultButton component has property `text-align: center;`. You can check in their official docs. What I suggest you should do is try `text-align: left;` If that does not override fabric's css rule, then try to see if your rule is applied, since maybe fabric's rule have greater specificity then your css rule. If this does not work, then you need to override fabric's display property and say the following:

```
.CollapsibleSection {
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex; //overriding fabric's display inline-block;
  justify-content: flex-start:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just had to add `text-align: left` to make it work

```
.CollapsibleSection {
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer:

```
justify-content: flex-start
```

---

If you'd like to learn more about it you can play this wonderful game which will give you a good knowledge about flexbox and positioning within it.

https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: The game link looks very tangential and should be a comment.

Comment: @tripleee it's a addition to the main content, which is adding a CSS rule to fix it